# What ISO code does the Accept-Language HTTP Header use?

Tags: http, browser, http-headers

What ISO code is used in the language section of the Accept-Language header (ie es for Spanish, de for German and en for English)

Is it ISO 639-1?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it ISO 639-1?

One could think that. And indeed, the format draws (among others) from ISO 639-1 and 639-3. To make this short: The `Accept-Language` header is under authority of [RFC 7231, section 5.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.5). The list of therein allowed language tags is referring to [RFC 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646) which is in turn pointing to the [IANA Language Subtag Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry). To my knowledge, this format does not directly map to any ISO code at all. See also: [Wikipedia: IETF Language Tag - Relation to other standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag#Relation_to_other_standards).

Comment: Chapter 2.1 actually directly refers to ISO 639 and states both 2 and 3 char codes are acceptable.

Comment: Actually it states that the shortest possible ISO 639 code must be used. So you can't use `fra` from 639-3 – you must use `fr` from 639-1.

Comment: Oh dear, [RFC 5646, sec. 2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5646#section-2.1) does indeed say that. This is complicating things a lot. If you read further into that section, you will realise that the list of acceptable language tags is not simply a superset of ISO 639-1. I will update my answer shortly.